# Accessing $_SESSION / $_GET / ... with dynamic variable

Tags: php, dynamic-variables

I have a class that takes care of all the user-related data.
In one of my methods i want to access `$_SESSION` / `$_GET`, `$_POST`, any `$_...`

via a dynamic var like following (in _unset method):

```
class Userdata
{
    ...
    const knownSources = ['post', 'get', 'cookie', 'session', 'files'];
    private $post = [];
    private $get = [];
    private $cookie = [];
    private $session = [];
    private $files = [];

    ...
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->post = $this->secureVars($_POST);
        $this->get = $this->secureVars($_GET);
        $this->cookie = $this->secureVars($_COOKIE);
        ...
    }
    public static function getInstance(){...}
    public static function secureVars($inputVar, $asObject = true, $acceptHTML = false){...}

    public static function _unset($dataSource, $key)
    {
        $self = self::getInstance();

        if (in_array(strtolower($dataSource), self::knownSources))
        {
            // Here I want to unset the variable in $_SESSION[$key] for instance, but 'SESSION' can be whichever of knownSources array. 
            print_r([
                ${'_SESSION'},
                ${'_' . 'SESSION'},
                ${'_' . strtoupper($dataSource)}
            ]);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why `${'_SESSION'}` works but not `${'_' . 'SESSION'}`?
And how to perform my goal: `${'_' . strtoupper($dataSource)}`?

Thanks for your help!

[EDIT]
AFTER SUGGESTIONS, I came to this:

```
switch($dataSource)
{
    case 'session':
        $target = $_SESSION;
        break;
    case 'post':
        $target = $_POST;
        break;
    case 'get':
        $target = $_GET;
        break;
    case 'cookie':
        $target = $_COOKIE;
        break;
    case 'files':
        $target = $_FILES;
        break;
}
unset($self->$dataSource->$key);
unset($target[$key]);
```

[EDIT]
AFTER REALISING IT STILL WON'T WORK, I - sadly - opt for:

```
    switch($dataSource)
    {
        case 'session':
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            break;
        case 'post':
            unset($_POST[$key]);
            break;
        case 'get':
            unset($_GET[$key]);
            break;
        case 'cookie':
            unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
            break;
        case 'files':
            unset($_FILES[$key]);
            break;
    }
    unset($self->$dataSource->$key);
```

Any smarter suggestion much appreciated :)

Comment: 3rd note: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Hmm, so is there any way I can workaround?

Comment: Make a if or switch statement to decide which superglobal you need.

Comment: I see, thanks. I can do it but I hope to find something even nicer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Url 
//?dangerous=yes&safe=keep

class MyClass {

    public static function _unset($datasource, $key) {
        global $$datasource;
        unset(${$datasource}[$key]);
    }

}

MyClass::_unset('_GET', 'dangerous');

//Test
print_r($_GET);
```

You are missing the `global` keyword.

Comment: Correct for missing the global keyword! Thank you!
So i transformed my variable name `$dataSource = '_'.strtoupper($dataSource);` first, and then do `global $$dataSource;`  and `unset(${$dataSource}[$key]);`